# Xcode compiles for Mac even if it is not in the platforms field in the Swift.package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift-package-manager

I would like to create a Swift library package just for iOS, and not for Mac. Therefore, i have a package file as follows:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    platforms: [
      .iOS(.v11)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Example",
            targets: ["Example"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Example",
                path: "Example/Example")
    ]
)
```

As you can see, I do not include Mac in the platforms. However, when I try to build from the package, it fails with:

```
ReplayKit is not available when building for macOS. Consider using `#if !os(macOS)` to conditionally import this framework.
```

And same for any type not available for Mac. How can I solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately, until Swift 5.2, you have to use the conditional imports:
https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-exclude-platforms-in-spm/32296/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `platforms` section of the package is the minimum deployment targets of the specified platforms not a list of platforms the package supports. So if you don't specify `.macOS(...)` then you get the default which is believe is `.v10_10`.

Unfortunately that means you have to determine what is available and put int inside of `#if !os(macOS)` blocks like the build error says.